# Bind mount issue with Go docker container running air

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I feel like I have a Catch 22 situation.

In my container, I wanted to place all shell scripts related to the container inside ./scripts for organisation purposes.

However, they run scripts, .e.g, `make dev` whereby the Makefile is in the root of the project.

So, inside my Dockerfile, I simple move things around to ensure they have the correct scope and are run at the correct directory level:

```
COPY --from=build /app .
COPY --from=build /app/scripts/air.sh /app/air.sh
COPY --from=build /app/scripts/start.sh /app/start.sh
COPY --from=build /app/scripts/tailscale.sh /app/tailscale.sh
COPY --from=tailscale /app/tailscaled /app/tailscaled
COPY --from=tailscale /app/tailscale /app/tailscale
```

Yet, to configure [cosmotrek/air](https://github.com/cosmtrek/air) inside my container, I have added this line to my bind volumes inside local.yaml:

```yaml
   volumes:
      - .:/app
```

Which completely undoes the work inside the `Dockerfile` ... essentially, the scripts no longer run from the root of the project when inside the container if I just bind the volumes.

I have tried all manner of volume bindings in the docker compose `local.yaml` file, but none seem to work. Specifically, because I build a Tailscale VPN inside the container's `Dockerfile`, I am not able to utilise this when specifying bind volumes in the docker compose file.

Now, WTF ... is this a bug or a feature? To me, it is a bug and the docker compose file is not respecting the `Dockerfile` ... hoping for a workaround here?

Comment: You are mounting a directory on top of `/app`. That will of course hide any existing content in that directory -- that's how filesystem mounts work in general; it's not a Docker thing. You'll need to use two different locations if you want to utilize both files provisioned in the image and files exposed via a bind mount.